# Is it possible for one Django model to inherit from two other models, one as abstract, one as proxy?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible for one model to both inherit from abstract model, while acting as proxy model of another?

```py
from django.db import models

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        abstract: true

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# Is this possible?
class MyCar(Car, Vehicle):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Would `MyCar` be a proxy of `Car` with the added fields from `Vehicle`?

Comment: It is not possible to create a *proxy* table in this manner, because the columns belonging to the abstract model don't have a location in the database to store data in.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Perhaps you have a tip for me - I am trying to extend the django.contrib.admin LogEntry model to have one more field. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should ask that question instead.  This is a classic case of the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica ha, ok nice info there. I'll revise!